# Что означает аббревиатура SCN в базе данных Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Нашел три возможных варианта:

- System Commit Number,
- System Checkpoint Number,
- System Change Number.

Который из них правильный?

Comment: [http://my-oracle.it-blogs.com.ua/post-417.aspx][1]

[1]: http://my-oracle.it-blogs.com.ua/post-417.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылка по теме. Получается, что SCN - это всегда System Change Number, но в некоторых случаях он может одновременно являться и System Commit Number, и System Checkpoint Number.